# Finding solutions for the differential equation: $x(y^2-7)-(x^2-6)yy'=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation: $x(y^2-7)-(x^2-6)yy'=0.$

How do I find a solution for the equation that satisfies $y(1)=-2$ (if it exists) or $y(\sqrt{-6})=-2$.

I know that I need to solve this equation so I rearranged the equation in this way:

$\frac{y}{y^2-7} y'= \frac{x}{x^2-6}$

but  I stuck at this point, how do I solve this?

any kind of help/directing would be appreciated.

Comment: $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$. So you have $\frac{y}{y^2-7} dy=\frac{x}{x^2-6} dx$ integrate both sides.

Comment: And if you question is how to do that. I think a substitution would just be fine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac{ydy}{y^2-7}=\int \frac{xdx}{x^2-6}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\log(y^2-7)=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2-6)+C$$

rearrange and take the exponential to get 
$$\frac{y^2-7}{x^2-6}=K$$
so the K is constant

Comment: Why does the C is only added to the right side?

Comment: You do a constant of integration on both sides but the difference of two constants is still constant.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani because the C is constant

Comment: Do you mean by $K$ here $e^{2c}$ ?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani yes

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side can be integrated by doing this: Let $u=x^2-6$ and so $\frac{1}{2} du=x dx$ So we have $\int \frac{x}{x^2-6} dx=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u}=\frac{1}{2} \ln|u|+C_1=\frac{1}{2} \ln|x^2-6|+C_1$. The left hand side can be done in a similar way. $\int \frac{y}{y^2-7} dy=\frac{1}{2} \ln|y^2-7|+C_2$. So we have $\frac{1}{2} \ln|y^2-7|+C_2=\frac{1}{2} \ln|x^2-6|+C_1$ Subtracting $C_2$ on both sides gives  $\frac{1}{2} \ln|y^2-7|=\frac{1}{2} \ln|x^2-6|+C_1-C_2$. But $C_1-C_2=C$. So we have $\frac{1}{2} \ln|y^2-7|=\frac{1}{2} \ln|x^2-6|+C$. We can also multiply 2 on both sides. $ \ln|y^2-7|= \ln|x^2-6|+2C$. Now recall $e^{\ln|x|}=|x|$ since $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=ln|x|$ are inverse functions of one another. So we have $e^{\ln|y^2-7|}=e^{\ln|x^2-6|+2C}$  By law of exponents we can rewrite the right hand side so we have $e^{\ln|y^2-7|}=e^{\ln|x^2-6|}e^{2C}$. Now using the inverse thingy we have $|y^2-7|=|x^2-6|K$. Went ahead and replaced $e^{2C}$ with $K$ since again $e^{2C}$ is a constant ( $K$ is positive by the way ) . So we have $K=| \frac{y^2-7}{x^2-6}|$

Comment: Wow, thanks, I appreciate it.